# How do you clear form inputs when a model changes in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form that has some common inputs and inputs that are specific to a model 'type'. When a user selects a certain 'type', from a select dropdown, these specific fields change. I'm using ng-include to include the specific 'partial' based on model.type. In 'edit' mode, how can I reset these specific inputs when the model 'type' changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ng-change` property on the `select`.

Then tie it to a function which clears the models that are bound to your form inputs (e.g. sets to `''`).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmalancea/vwswckrr/)

Comment: Does ng-change 'remember' the original values? If for example, the user changes the model.type, but then changes it back to the original, will the original values be there?

Comment: No. You will need to add instructions to save the values and look them up when it changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an angular $watch to watch a variable.  See the Watch section in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

```
    $scope.$watch('type', function () {
        //do stuff
    });
```

Comment: `$watch` is certainly a solution, but it should be used sparingly since it gets triggered every `$digest` cycle (almost every times something changes in the app).